# How to disable potential security concern pop up while adding a page in Word document using Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I add a Word document (docx) into an existing Word document.

```vb
Sub InsertFile()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Disclaimer.docx", Link:=True
End Sub
```

How to disable this pop up while running the macro?

[image]

I tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert the content instead of creating a link by using

`Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\user\Downloads\Disclaimer.docx", Link:=False`

Answer (score 0):

**File** -> **Options** -> **Trust Center** -> **Trust Center Settings** -> Check **Enable All Macros**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create and open your Word Object and perform whatever you are doing,
Set ObjWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = ObjWord.Documents.Add
NewDocumentName = ObjWord.ActiveDocument ' Use this to toggle back to your primary document when pasting

Your awesome code here
Your awesome code here
Your awesome code here
Your awesome code here

Then when you need to insert a document, or a part of a document do the following.

Dim docToInsert As Object
Set docToInsert = ObjWord.Documents.Open(YourDocumentFileNameHere)
docToInsert.Content.Copy

Set objDoc = ObjWord.Documents(NewDocumentName) ' Set the focus back to your primary document
objDoc.Activate
DoEvents ' This seems to help, I know not usually used, but on my PC, it seems to help.
ObjWord.Selection.Paste

Note, once you have done everything you will then need to close all the opened documents which is easy

' Close word and every document without being prompted to save
For Each objDoc In ObjWord.Documents
objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next objDoc
ObjWord.Quit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).